# How to use a basic page's alias as a contextual filter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a basic page called *Kids* with an alias path of: `example.com/kids`

I also have a content type called *Resources* that has tags.

I want to create a block that gets all *Resources* with the tag "kids" or whatever the basic page's alias is. I do not want to create a block with a hard-coded filter for each basic page.

I created a view, and set the contextual filter to be the first parameter of the URL, expecting that to be the basic page's alias. Unfortunately this does not work because the contextual filter seems to start AFTER the alias.

`example.com/kids` returns no results.

`example.com/kids/kids` behaves how I would like and returns all Resources tagged with kids. However, if I create a second basic page nested under Kids, it stops working as `kids/kids` is now a valid alias path, so the contextual filter ignores it.

tl;dr;

Are there any modules or ways of using a basic page's alias as the contextual filter?

Thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same problem - did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 1):

In the contextual filters settings you can select to set a default value when one is not passed (which is what is happening with your alias).  You can then write some PHP that returns that last part of the page alias.

something along the lines of:

```
return array_pop(explode('/',drupal_get_path_alias()));
```

So now when you go to "example.com/kids" the contextual filter will have the argument 'kids'.

Same is for the aliased path "example.com/kids/kids".

Answer (score 0):

Even I face the same problem once.
This is what i did.

made a callback / menu named X, and passed it onto a menu like X/A, where A is the argument "kids" in your case.
Now with URL alias, rewrite this URL as X/A to A

This way it worked for me flawlessly and still is working.